# Monitor Spring Boot JMX with Zabbix

Tags: zabbix

Spring Boot JMX values are Jsons like

```
{    
    "mem": 986624,
    "mem.free": 933858,
    "processors": 8,
    "threads": 15,
    "threads.daemon": 11,
    "threads.peak": 15,
    "threads.totalStarted": 42,
    "uptime": 494836,
    "instance.uptime": 489782,
    "datasource.primary.active": 5,
    "datasource.primary.usage": 0.25
}
```

How can I configure Zabbix to read and count, for example,  `datasource.primary.usage`? Is there any way of doing it except writing some complex script in Zabbix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON parsing in item values is not currently supported in Zabbix. It is allegedly coming in Zabbix 3.4.